# Shortest path between multiple points

Tags: flutter, maps

I need to add a feature to my existing app. I have clients named a,b,c,d and e in my application. I know the locations (as latitude and longitude) of these customers. I want to visit customers a,b,c,d and e. When I set out from where I am, I want to visit from the closest person to the farthest person. Just like a shipping company. I want to create a road map that will allow me to visit my customers as soon as possible and get directions with a navigation application such as Google Maps. Is it possible for me to do this with Google Maps or a different API service?

Comment: You can try to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/google_directions_api

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the following API can be used to obtain the route between each place.

#### □ google_directions_api

The Directions API is a service that calculates directions between locations. You can search for directions for several modes of transportation, including transit, driving, walking, or cycling.

As you said, each path to C, D and E requires implementation via custom.
Finding a single path can be implemented like the following example:

```dart
import 'package:google_directions_api/google_directions_api.dart';

void main() {
  DirectionsService.init('API_KEY');

  final directionsService = DirectionsService();

  final request = DirectionsRequest(
    origin: 'New York',
    destination: 'San Francisco',
    travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
  );

  directionsService.route(request,
      (DirectionsResult response, DirectionsStatus status) {
    if (status == DirectionsStatus.ok) {
      // do something with successful response
    } else {
      // do something with error response
    }
  });
}
```

This example is from https://pub.dev/packages/google_directions_api.
Please refer to pub for details :)